# getJson not get any data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with mvc4 and c#

i have a controller action like,

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetChildCategories(int id)
    {
        Category cat = new Category(id);
        List<Category> child = new Categories().ToList(cat);  //get two list items when jquery calling
        return Json(child, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and i am try to call these action using a jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = '/Add/GetChildCategories/1';
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    alert(data);   //alert is not working
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {           
        alert(key);  //alert is not working
    });
});
});
```

when calling these,list `child` contain two items, but that value is not getting in `data`.

Comment: Is your `GetChildCategories` is getting called or not?

Comment: @vallabha: yes it is called, and have values in the list

Comment: What happens if you hit the URL directly from browser? Are you getting a json file download with records? Also try using : url='@Url.Action("GetChildCategories","ControllerName",new{id=1})'

Comment: @SivaGopal: it shows the error'RecursionLimit exceeded.'

Comment: Exactly where and when are you getting that error? In client-side/controller/objects you are using?

Comment: What does `new Categories().ToList(cat);` do?

Comment: @SivaGopal: when hitting controller action there is no error, i think when it return to view that time error occur

Comment: @StephenMuecke: that take a list from dbase based on the model properties Category

Comment: I suspect that where the problem is. Post the code for that method.

Comment: Try using a query string: /Add/GetChildCategories?id=1

Comment: @shyama, If `alert(data);` is not working, no data is being returned which means your throwing an exception in the controller method (check the browser console for errors). It's almost certainly `new Categories().ToList(cat);` that's the problem. Just comment out the first 2 lines and replace with `List<Category> child = new List<Category>() { new Category(id) };` and try it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 public ActionResult GetChildCategories(int id)        {
        Category cat = new Category(id);
        List<Category> child = new Categories().ToList(cat);
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(child);
         }
```

or
try changing your JS function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
            url: '{BaseURL}/Add/GetChildCategories/1,
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function (data) {
            var jsonData= JSON.parse(data);
            alert(jsonData)
        });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you hit the URL directly from browser? Are you getting a json file download with records?

Also try using : url='@Url.Action("GetChildCategories","ControllerName",new{id=1})' and it is a safe way to generate updated outgoing URLs in case your route templates are changed in future.

What is happening, if you use just: $.get(...) instead of $.getJson(...)?

Comment: @shyama 'When hitting controller action there is no error'.. did you check with break point in controller that, your client call is reaching to controller but unable to render on the client?

Comment: If yes,as the 'recursion limit exceeded' says, I guess there should be some deep nesting within your objects happening. Try hitting the URL from browser and see if you get the JSON file downloadable with records..

Comment: hit the URL directly from browser and url='@Url.Action("GetChildCategories","ControllerName",new{id=1})'  :it shows the error'RecursionLimit exceeded.

Comment: and get the same using $.get(..)

Comment: @shyama, you should use eg: http://yourdomain/Add/GetChildCategories/1 in browser . @URL.Action(...) should be used in View code only.